# DXA 2.0 JAVA microservice in Linux

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, microservices, linux

I've installed CD microservices in Linux by creating '{service-name}.service' files in /etc/systemd/system/ and registering them.

All the CD microservices run well.

I tried to create in such way DXA microservice but it fails on start up. 
Here is a 'dxa.service' content:

```
[Unit]
Description=DXA Model Service for SDL Staging
After=network.target staging-discovery.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/sdl/sdl-8.5/microservices/staging/dxa/cis/dxa-model-service/standalone/bin/start.sh
ExecStop=/opt/sdl/sdl-8.5/microservices/staging/dxa/cis/dxa-model-service/standalone/bin/stop.sh
PIDFile=/opt/sdl/sdl-8.5/microservices/staging/dxa/cis/dxa-model-service/standalone/bin/sdl-service-container.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So it fails with a message in console like this:

> Job for staging-dxa-model.service failed because a timeout was
>   exceeded. See "systemctl status staging-dxa-model.service" and
>   "journalctl -xe" for details.

I also tried to add parameter to .service file 'TimeoutStartSec=6000' but same issue but takes longer time =)

Does anybody has experience in creating DXA service in Linux (CentOS 7 x64)?

Here is a part of cd_client log file:

> 2018-09-07 13:45:37,060 WARN  c.s.w.c.c.c.i.BaseClientConfigurationLoader - ?>Unable to resolve ContentServiceCapability using DiscoveryService: >http://10.6.218.86:8182/discovery.svc. 
>   com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientRuntimeException: Unable to call >OData service for "http://10.6.218.86:8182/discovery.svc" URL and service query >"/TokenServiceCapabilities"

But discovery service returns

```
"error": "invalid_grant"
```

So it works I believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Jeroen Suurd](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/251/jeroen-suurd) the problem was fixed.

I've made a mistake in 'dxa.service' for PIDFile, should be as follows:

```
PIDFile=/opt/sdl/sdl-8.5/microservices/staging/dxa/cis/dxa-model-service/standalone/sdl-service-container.pid
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you registered the content service in the discovery service? The message states that ContentServiceCapability can’t be resolved, so I would start checking there.

Comment: Yes, it is registered and I can access the link http://bla-bla:port/content.svc